# Use RMI interface implementation in other module (intellij)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rmi

i have RMI project in Intellij.
I have one package with interfaces (package named common) and also other server package with interface implementations.

When i tried to register my service inside Main class on server package i do something like

Note: Remote service is also a base interface for services defined in interface module.

```
private static void registerService(RemoteService service) throws RemoteException {
        LocateRegistry.getRegistry().rebind("service", ServiceImpl.getInstance());
    }
```

But it gives me a ClassNotFoundException because he cannot found ServiceInterface.java (It´s in interface module), i have interface module as a dependency as compile scope in server module.. What 'm doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't deploying the common Jar correctly.

Comment: I'm adding common module as a dependencies for the others one

Comment: Code compiles and also could execute a static method from a static class of common package so i think u are wrong